# New user configuration

Tags: configuration, users, dropbox

I want to make my Dropbox directory secure from unwitting changes. So I made for my directory and files inside the following actions:

```
chown -R dropbox:dropbox Dropbox
```

The idea is that I work under a common user, let's name it USER. And I start dropbox as dropbox user:

```
sudo -u dropbox dropbox start
```

But there is an error and I don't know how to handle it:

```
Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?
```

How can I create a new user properly, in a way that achieves this goal? Currently the only configuration files in `/home/dropbox` directory are from `/etc/skel/` directory.

**UPDATE To the suggestion of Eliah Kagan:**

I cannot start dropbox with gksu, when I am trying to do that I get this:

```
gksu -u dropbox dropbox start -i
gksu: option requires an argument -- 'i'
```

Under dropbox user:

```
dropbox start -i
Starting Dropbox...No protocol specified
No protocol specified
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/bin/dropbox:406: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  title = "Dropbox Installation")
/usr/bin/dropbox:406: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion     `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  title = "Dropbox Installation")
/usr/bin/dropbox:414: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion     `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.ok = ok = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_OK)
/usr/bin/dropbox:414: Warning: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)'     failed
  self.ok = ok = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_OK)
/usr/bin/dropbox:414: Warning: value "TRUE" of type `gboolean' is invalid or     out of range for property `visible' of type `gboolean'
  self.ok = ok = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_OK)
/usr/bin/dropbox:419: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion     `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  cancel = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_CANCEL)
/usr/bin/dropbox:419: Warning: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)'     failed
  cancel = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_CANCEL)
/usr/bin/dropbox:419: Warning: value "TRUE" of type `gboolean' is invalid or out of range for property `visible' of type `gboolean'
  cancel = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_CANCEL)
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: GtkWarning: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion `context != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion `context != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_language: assertion `context != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_new: assertion `context != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_text: assertion `layout != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_attributes: assertion `layout != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion `layout != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_width: assertion `layout != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion `layout != NULL' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_wrap: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion `GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  dialog.show()
/usr/bin/dropbox:486: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_window_new: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
  dialog.show()
Segmentation fault
```

This errors tell that something is wrong with the user graphics environment configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The Dropbox client you are using requires access to an X session, which your user doesn't have. [There is an official Dropbox CLI](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI) that may do the trick for you, but mileage may vary.

Comment: I know about CLI client, but I want use GUI version. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Agee has said, `dropbox` is a graphical program, so you [should not use `sudo` directly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) to run it as root.

However, you shouldn't have any problems running programs graphically as another user, so long as you do it correctly:

```
gksu -u dropbox dropbox start
```

To be clear, **this should work**, where `sudo -u ...` doesn't. (Preventing the creation of `root`-owned--or in this case, `dropbox`-owned--configuration files in *your* home directory is not the only difference between `gksu`/`gksudo` and `sudo`; the former also handles `.Xauthority` properly, which is probably what's preventing you from "access[ing] the X Display.")

Comment: I used sudo for other programs with GUI before many times. "This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by Root" -  I suppose that it is the main distinguishment from sudo. But I don't care about it, because I work in the home directory of a dropbox user.

Comment: @user14416 Have you tried this with `gksu`? See edit.

Comment: FYI: it worked when i did : `gksudo python /var/tmp/p.py`